# How to show an activity on top of lock screen without dismissing the lockscreen?

Tags: android

I am trying to bring my activity on top of lock screen in android. My Activity is not a full screen activity. Activity layout is like an alert but it is an activity. With `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`, I am able to bring my activity on top of lock screen. Only issue is every time my activity is launched, it dismisses the lock screen even though it is a secure lock screen and I am not using `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`. I see my device's Home screen till my activity is finished. Once my activity is finished, Lock Screen comes back in focus. Is there any way I can show my activity without dismissing the lock screen ?

Comment: wait, clarification - how does the user start up your activity with a lock screen?

Comment: @Abhi: do not put tags in subject

Comment: @DavidT. irrelevant. it can be launched by alarm.

Comment: @David : It can be a incoming call or alarm as mentioned by WebnetMobile.com

Comment: Some code would help